# Why does using `this` within function give me a "Possible strict violation" in jshint?

Tags: javascript, this, jshint

Say I have a function that I would like reuse as a method on a couple objects in order to add data to those objects.

```
function addToObject(data) {
  for (var d in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
      this[d] = data[d];
    }
  }
}

myObjOne = {
  add: addToObject
};

myObjTwo = {
  add: addToObject
};
```

My goal here was to be able to call `myObjOne.add(myData)` where `myData` is an object that I would like to add to `myObjOne` and be able to replicate this functionality on `myObjTwo`.

My issue is that using `this` within `addToObject` gives me:

```
this[d] = data[d];
^ Possible strict violation.
```

in jshint.

Why is this?

Comment: This is asked a lot.  It's a wrong warning by jshint.  As long as you call `addToObject()` properly (which sets `this` appropriately), there is no strict violation.

Comment: Good to know. Is there a way to suppress this warning?

Comment: I believe `jsHint` has a way to disable this warning.

Comment: AHA http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say the warning happens when:

> you use `this` in a non-constructor function. If you forget to use the `new` keyword when calling a constructor function, `this` will be bound unexpectedly to the global object in non-strict mode, but will be undefined in strict mode.

Use `validethis:true` in a pragma comment:

```
function addToObject(data) {
    'use strict';
    var d;
    for (d in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
            /* jshint: validthis:true */
            this[d] = data[d];
        }
    }
}
```

**References**

- [JsHint Options: validthis](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis)
- [The Strict Mode Restriction and Exceptions](http://people.w3.org/mike/bugs/es5-spec/#C)

Comment: But what does the warning mean?

Comment: The docs say the warning happens when: `you use this in a non-constructor function`. If you forget to use the `new` keyword when calling a constructor function, `this` will be bound unexpectedly to the global object in [non-strict mode](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/), but will be `undefined` in strict mode.